# Blender image editor path on Linux

Tags: image, customization, external-applications

I'm running Blender on the latest version of Mint and was wondering how could I set up Edit->Preferences->File Paths->Image Editor path to Krita. I have an appimage installed but that does not seem to work for Blender. I've also tried with Gimp, which gives me

Error: Image editor could not be launched, ensure that the path in User Preferences > File is valid, and Blender has rights to launch it.

It does not display any error when pressing Quick Edit, it just won't open :/

Comment: Setting Krita as an external editor works for me. Does the Krita .appimage have it's executable flag set and is your user it's owner?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what could cause it. I just went back to Windows for now, since I couldn't find anything.

Comment: That's unfortunate... You'll find the Linux Blender experience much more satisfying, it's generally faster across the board. Were you using Blender downloaded from https://www.blender.org/?

Comment: Yes, if I remember it right.